# Solana - How to get cluster versions

Tags: solana

How do I get the cluster versions on Solana?

For example, I'd like to know the current version of the devnet cluster.

Is there a command line or website which tells me the current versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a CLI and here is a link to how to get the cluster version.

https://docs.solana.com/cli/choose-a-cluster#ensure-versions-match